# Generate known_hosts with TFS git server

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, tfs

I need to configure ssh for Jenkins server. For this I need to get a /.ssh with known_hosts file. There is written that easiest way to get it, is to use command:

```
  c:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe" -T git@your.git.server
```

What should I put instead "your.git.server" if I'm using git from the TFS.

For example I'm working with project and full link to clone it is:

```
  https://myserver.com:8080/tfs/CollectionName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName/
```

I tried different combinations but nothing is working. For this command:

```
  ssh -T git@myserver.com:8080/tfs/CollectionName/ProjectName/_git
```

I got error message: "ssh: Could not resolve hostname myserver.com:8080/tfs/CollectionName/ProjectName/_git: not address associated with name"

Answer (score 3):

Currently, TFS (2105 update 2) has no support for SSH, but it is scheduled to appear in a non-distant future (see [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3801342-add-support-for-ssh-keys-as-alternate-authenticati) and [timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx)).

In the meantime you can use [Git Credential Manager](https://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/gitcredentialmanager) to authenticate with TFS from Windows, Mac or Linux.

Yet another option is to use [Git Credential Store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) with Basic Authentication and SSL. This is a non default configuration so you have to agree with the TFS Administrator if it is feasible. I would not recommend as a first choice as it is easy to screw security.